# decode the word in a way that every letter x, if it is the ith letter of the alpha starting from the left, replace it with the ith chara from right

Tags: python, string

Problem

The code is to decode the word in such a way that For every letter x, if it is the ith letter of

the alphabet starting from the left, replace it with the ith letter starting from the right.

. For example, the string 'abcd' would be encoded to 'zyxw'.

Note: all the letters of the word are lower case alphabets

Editorial:

"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" is the sequence.

⚫ Here a is the fist alphabet appear in the sequence, so it will be replaced with the last

alphabet in the sequence i.e. z. ⚫b is the second alphabet from the begining in the sequence, so it will be replaced by the second last alphabet from the end i.e. y, and so on.

⚫ Here a is the fist alphabet appear in the sequence, so it will be replaced with the last

alphabet in the sequence i.e. z. ⚫b is the second alphabet from the begining in the sequence, so it will be replaced by the second last alphabet from the end i.e. y, and so on.

Comment: This smells like a homework problem...

Comment: have a table and do a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of doing your homework for you...

```
def codeword(word: str) -> str:
    ABC = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    encoded_chars = [ABC[-ABC.index(char) - 1] for char in word.lower()]
    return ''.join(encoded_chars)


print(codeword('aaa'))
# => 'zzz'
print(codeword('abc'))
# => 'zyx'
print(codeword('stackoverflow')
# => 'hgzxpleviuold'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of the alphabet you find the index of that letter and then word backwords with the letter index it works, you can also modify the code to get a different encoding.

```
def translate_words(stringw):
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q","r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
newstring=""
stringw = stringw.lower()
for count, letter in enumerate(stringw):
    if letter in alphabet:
        letternum = alphabet.index(letter)
        newstring += alphabet[25-letternum]
return newstring
print(translate_words("abcd"))
```

Comment: Strings in Python are already iterables, so you don't need to declare a list of alphabet characters! You can just do `alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'` :)

Comment: that would have saved me a lot of pressing repeated keystrokes

Comment: Hah, I feel you. Happy to help out.